# Highcharts - How can I decrease space between categories?

Tags: jquery, graph, highcharts

[image: Example for question]

I need to reduce that space, ... How can I do it?

"Planificación", "prioridad" and "gerencia" are categories, the numbers inside are series by person.

Comment: Example: http://bit.ly/My5fOY   , reduce space between fruits categories

Comment: @rolivares, whats character in ur avatar?

Comment: Is part of a picture taken by me in Brasil (Santa Catarina), I do not know if there is a character associated. Is just a Clown from theatre, like this http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jRsnOJhsypg.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To do this [pointPadding](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#plotOptions-bar--pointPadding) and [pointWidth](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#plotOptions-bar--pointWidth) are what you want.

Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/M85tL/).
The important bits are:

```
plotOptions: {
            series: {
                stacking: 'normal',
                pointWidth: 50,
                pointPadding: 0
            }
        },
```

Comment: Good answer, you could also use the height and width properties of the chart in conjunction with what wergeld suggested to get the look exactly the way you want it like: [**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/M85tL/1/).  Me personally, I don't like the bars so thick.

Comment: Aye, that was a LOOK SEE THEY ARE DIFFERENT example. I prefer a little bit of spacing and limiting the overall size of the chart as well - and increasing the chart size if I increase my categories so that they are all not squished together.

Comment: Both answers were helpful, because the first one has helped me to decrease the bars height and the second has helped me to decrease the space between bars. I was setting a larger chart height than the I needed. Thanks guys.

Comment: This doesn't work, not even in the jsfiddle :( The only reason the padding is small is because the chart is small. Changing pointWith to 10 makes this obvious.

Comment: It does work. Increasing the bar width decreases the gap between category lines. Yes, the height of the chart is a determining factor in this case (roughly height/#categories = category spacing). If you look at the initial code the OP posted and this code you can see that the gap was lessened. This works under highcharts 2.x and 3.x - the answer was to increase the `pointWidth` to accommodate the hard-coded gap that highcharts uses based on the size and number of categories. Still not sure what you were expecting.