# highchart: How to Remove Series space (after & before)

Tags: charts, highcharts, margin, series, axis-labels

i went to remove space(gape) from between two series.

check image for more detail !

http://s13.postimg.org/4nklby5vb/10_Sep_14_7_46_01_PM.png

Comment: I think this can help:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11142378/highcharts-how-can-i-decrease-space-between-categories

Comment: nice example, but my requirement different. i went to remove space between 2 groups ( please see image )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Space between columns you can control by [groupPadding](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.groupPadding) / [pointPadding](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.pointPadding)